# Using count for counting sets of values of integer column

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to the world of SQL. I would like to know how many stores are at each location based on the `location_id`. I know for a fact that count is going to be needed. When i run the query below i get no results due to an error?

`SELECT COUNT(location_id) FROM stores`

Table:

```
stores

ID Location_id Store_Name
-- ----------- ----------
1      1         Example1
2      1         Example2
3      2         Example3
4      2         Example4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  Location_id,count(Store_Name)
from stores
group by Location_id
```

This query will return the `Location_Id` followed by `number of stores` in that location for each location.

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the records by location and count them. You can use most [aggregate functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) with group by statement .

```
 SELECT LOCATION_ID, COUNT(*) FROM stores GROUP BY LOCATION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Location_id, COUNT(Store_Name) as count FROM stores
group by Location_id
```